# How can I combine these HTML files in order to run them at the same time on a single webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

My knowledge of HTML/Javascript is extremely limited. I was working with this code I found online, and wanted to combine the two programs so that I had the brickbreaker game on top, and the live data updating beneath it. The two activities don't need to be linked, but want them to appear on the same webpage, both within view without having to scroll. I appreciate any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var dataPoints1 = [];
var dataPoints2 = [];
var dataPoints3 = [];

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Protein Activity"
    },
    axisX: {
        title: "chart updates every 1 secs"
    },
    axisY:{
        prefix: "",
        includeZero: false
    },
    toolTip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        cursor:"pointer",
        verticalAlign: "top",
        fontSize: 22,
        fontColor: "dimGrey",
        itemclick : toggleDataSeries
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        xValueType: "dateTime",
        yValueFormatString: "####.00",
        xValueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Blue Protein",
        dataPoints: dataPoints1
        },
        {
            type: "line",
            xValueType: "dateTime",
            yValueFormatString: "####.00",
            xValueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss",
            showInLegend: true,
            name: "Red Protein" ,
            dataPoints: dataPoints2
    },
    {
        type: "line",
        xValueType: "dateTime",
        yValueFormatString: "####.00",
        xValueFormatString: "hh:mm:ss",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Green Protein" ,
        dataPoints: dataPoints3
}]
});

function toggleDataSeries(e) {
    if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
    }
    else {
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
    }
    chart.render();
}
//initial interval was 3000 (every 3 seconds)
var updateInterval = 1000; // 1 second interval 1000
// initial value originally 600 and 605
var yValue1 = 0;
var yValue2 = 0
var yValue3 = 0;

var time = new Date;
// starting at 9.30 am

time.setMinutes(00);
time.setSeconds(00);

function updateChart(count) {

    count = count || 1;
    var deltaY1, deltaY2, deltaY3;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        time.setTime(time.getTime() + updateInterval);
        // dropping the parenthetical manipulators
        // the change is between 0 and 1 ... place holder until we connect with the game
        deltaY1 =  Math.random() ;
        deltaY2 =  Math.random();
        deltaY3 =  Math.random();

    // adding random value and rounding it to two digits.
    yValue1 = Math.round((yValue1 + deltaY1)*100)/100;
    yValue2 = Math.round((yValue2 + deltaY2)*100)/100;
    yValue3 = Math.round((yValue3 + deltaY3)*100)/100;
    // pushing the new values
    dataPoints1.push({
        x: time.getTime(),
        y: yValue1
    });
    dataPoints2.push({
        x: time.getTime(),
        y: yValue2
    });
    dataPoints3.push({
        x: time.getTime(),
        y: yValue3
    });
    }

    // updating legend text with  updated with y Value
    chart.options.data[0].legendText = " Blue Protein:  " + yValue1;
    chart.options.data[1].legendText = " Red Protein:  " + yValue2;
    chart.options.data[2].legendText = " Green Protein:  " + yValue3;
    chart.render();

}
// generates first set of dataPoints
updateChart(0);
setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
    <style>
        * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var brickRowCount = 5;
var brickColumnCount = 3;
var brickWidth = 75;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
var score = 0;
var lives = 3;

var bricks = [];
for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
  bricks[c] = [];
  for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0, status: 1 };
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  if(relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
    paddleX = relativeX - paddleWidth/2;
  }
}
function collisionDetection() {
  for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      var b = bricks[c][r];
      if(b.status == 1) {
        if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brickHeight) {
          dy = -dy;
          b.status = 0;
          score++;
          if(score == brickRowCount*brickColumnCount) {
            alert("YOU WIN, CONGRATS!");
            document.location.reload();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
function drawPaddle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}
function drawBricks() {
  for(var c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(var r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
      if(bricks[c][r].status == 1) {
        var brickX = (r*(brickWidth+brickPadding))+brickOffsetLeft;
        var brickY = (c*(brickHeight+brickPadding))+brickOffsetTop;
        bricks[c][r].x = brickX;
        bricks[c][r].y = brickY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
    }
  }
}
function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 8, 20);
}
function drawLives() {
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fillText("Lives: "+lives, canvas.width-65, 20);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawBricks();
  drawBall();
  drawPaddle();
  drawScore();
  drawLives();
  collisionDetection();

  if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
  }
  if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
  }
  else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
    if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
      dy = -dy;
    }
    else {
      lives--;
      if(!lives) {
        alert("GAME OVER");
        document.location.reload();
      }
      else {
        x = canvas.width/2;
        y = canvas.height-30;
        dx = 3;
        dy = -3;
        paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
      }
    }
  }

  if(rightPressed && paddleX < canvas.width-paddleWidth) {
    paddleX += 7;
  }
  else if(leftPressed && paddleX > 0) {
    paddleX -= 7;
  }

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some of it is going to be CSS, some javascript I would use two pages, and then code two iframes in a third page to combine them but @simmer 's idea would work providing the javascript form each did not interfere with each other or the css.

Answer (score 0):

You could create different java script files separately and link them to the same HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, this is the approach you'll want to take in creating a new HTML page that combines the original two:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- contents of first page's <head> -->
  <!-- contents of second page's <head> -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- contents of first page's <body> -->
  <!-- contents of second page's <body> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you don't have any duplicate code (such as redundant `<title>` tags), make sure any elements with `id=""` attributes have unique ids, and you should be off to a good start.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses canvas or div elements for showing codes. You must put in body element:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

and

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

And if you don't have same function and variable names, you can add all the codes between `<script>` and `<script>`.

Your screen resolution is another problem. You can see "width" and "height" variables in `<canvas>` and `<div>` elements. If your screen resolution is enough for sum of heights (I think, it must be) you will see in one page two of them.